# Custom notification for desktop file to Android phone

Tags: android, python, linux

I have a csv file on my linux desktop that contains events in the future I need to be notified of. Currently, I have a python program made that emails me an hour before the event so I can act.

I used to have my Android phone set up so that if an email from my computer was received (sent through a google account) a unique sound would play. This distinguishes it from other emails.

After an Android update, this functionality is gone from Android phones.

I then used Twilio but am well past the free trial (I sent a text when the email was sent).

I have Airdroid on my phone but don't know how it can scan or read my file on a linux desktop to see when a notification is due.

The question is: what methods can I use to directly send a notification to my Android phone from a file on my desktop?

I am not sure if this is best Stack to ask this question so please advise if there is a better forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API of Pushbullet to accomplish this for free.
Then, their Android app is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I used the code here: https://simply-python.com/tag/pushbullet/ and installed on my phone. Cheers Ron.